# Mysql select all rows from table1 and matching rows from table2 or return null

Tags: mysql

I need to get all products columns plus the column unit_price from price_list where all the conditions match.

The problem is my select statement gets only the first 2 products, id: 1, 2, I need to get product with id 3,4 and so on, but with unit_price null because there is no match in price_list for that quantity.

```
products
--------------------------------------------
id  product_code    purchase_type   quantity
1   106             new             5
2   107             renew           26
3   107             renew           101
4   107             renew           150


price_list
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id  product_code    purchase_type   minimum     maximum     unit_price
1   106             new             1           25          20
2   106             new             26          50          16
3   106             new             51          100         14



SELECT
    `products`.`id` AS `product_id`,
    `products`.`product_code` AS `product_product_code`,
    `products`.`purchase_type` AS `product_purchase_type`,
    `products`.`update_type` AS `product_update_type`,
    `products`.`quantity` AS `product_quantity`,
    `price_list`.`product_code` AS `price_list_product_code`,
    `price_list`.`purchase_type` AS `price_list_purchase_type`,
    `price_list`.`update_type` AS `price_list_update_type`,
    `price_list`.`minimum` AS `price_list_minimum`,
    `price_list`.`maximum` AS `price_list_maximum`,
    `price_list`.`unit_price` AS `price_list_unit_price`
FROM
    `products`
INNER JOIN `price_list` ON `products`.`product_code` = `price_list`.`product_code`
WHERE
    `products`.`product_code` = price_list.product_code
AND `products`.`purchase_type` = price_list.purchase_type
AND `products`.`update_type` = price_list.update_type
AND `products`.`quantity` >= price_list.minimum
AND `products`.`quantity` <= price_list.maximum
ORDER BY
    `products`.`id` ASC
```

I would like my select statement to get me something like this:

```
    Select Result:
    -------------------------------------------------------
    id  product_code    purchase_type   quantity   unit_price
    1   106             new             5          20
    2   107             renew           26         16
    3   107             renew           101        null
    4   107             renew           150        null
```

Current select gets only id 1 and 2.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN , It will solve your problem...

Comment: LEFT JOIN no impact http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b562/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your possible solution is

```
    SELECT
    `products`.`id` AS `product_id`,
    `products`.`product_code` AS `product_product_code`,
    `products`.`purchase_type` AS `product_purchase_type`,
    `products`.`quantity` AS `product_quantity`,
    `price_list`.`product_code` AS `price_list_product_code`,
    `price_list`.`purchase_type` AS `price_list_purchase_type`,
    `price_list`.`minimum` AS `price_list_minimum`,
    `price_list`.`maximum` AS `price_list_maximum`,
    `price_list`.`unit_price` AS `price_list_unit_price`
FROM
    `products`
LEFT JOIN `price_list` ON `products`.`product_code` = `price_list`.`product_code`
AND `products`.`purchase_type` = price_list.purchase_type
AND `products`.`quantity` >= price_list.minimum
AND `products`.`quantity` <= price_list.maximum
ORDER BY
    `products`.`id` ASC
```

It will be better if you have more data with sqlfiddle link.

Comment: I have updated my query and you also check the query result in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b562/10